# localizing an excel servers report

Tags: excel, localization

Is there a way to produce an excel services report that can be localized for different languages. I have found this is possible in SSRS ([See Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294636/Localizing-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-Reports)) but cannot find any real confirmation for excel or exel services.

I have found the odd comment about excel report templates ([See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513084.aspx)) but cannot find any guide of how to implement.

My basic requirement is to have a report I create in excel for excel services and be able to make any labels I use localize to the language of the users regional settings

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is that it cannot be done and you would need duplicate reports for each language.